# Get entries by custom matrix / date time field

Tags: entries, matrix, datetime, ordering

I want to list all entries in a section by custom date time fields.

A training course has a From field and a To field. These fields are inside a *Matrix* field.

The field name storing this info is called `trainingDateTime`.

The Matrix block is called `trainingDateTimeDateTime`.

The Matrix fields in this block are called and `dateTimeFrom` and `dateTimeTo` both *datetime* fields.

My entries loop so far is:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section("training") %}
```

I know you can do order entries by a custom *datetime* field using something like:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section("training").customDateTime.('>= ' ~ now).order('customDateTime DESC') %}
```

But since I'm using a *matrix* field I'm unsure how to approach this.

I'm wanting to show all upcoming training courses from the current month up till the next 2 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by using the following:

```
{% set startDate = now %}
{% set endDate = (now | date_modify("+2 months")) %}
{% set allTraining = craft.lowblocks.blocks.fieldId(72).type("trainingDateTimeDateTime").order("dateTimeFrom").limit(null) %}
{% set entryIds = [] %}
{% for course in allTraining %}
    {% if (course.dateTimeFrom >= startDate) and (course.dateTimeFrom <= endDate) %}
        {% set entry = course.owner %}
        {% set entryIds = entryIds | merge([entry.id]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section("training").id(entryIds).fixedOrder(true).status("live,pending") %}
```

Comment: Is there any way in Craft 2.3 that this is doable without the use of a plugin? I have a matrix field with a date in it and I want to pull out the last 3 entries. 

Almost exactly what you have, but native.